# Story of Pesach during 2nd year in desert - Where did they get the dough for matzot?

Tags: passover, matzah, bo, behaalotcha-parsha, mon-manna

Rashi on Exodus 16:1:1:

> **בחמשה עשר יום.** נתפרש היום של חניה זו, לפי שבו ביום כלתה החררה
>   שהוציאו ממצרים והצרכו למן, למדנו שאכלו משירי הבצק [משירי המצה] ששים
>   ואחת סעודות, :

**Summary**: The Torah mentioned the date because until the 1st day of the 2nd month, they ate from the leftover matzot taken out of Egypt. Then, they ran out and needed the *mahn*

Numbers 9:1-3:

> וַיְדַבֵּ֣ר יְהוָ֣ה אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֣ה בְמִדְבַּר־סִ֠ינַי בַּשָּׁנָ֨ה
>   הַשֵּׁנִ֜ית לְצֵאתָ֨ם מֵאֶ֧רֶץ מִצְרַ֛יִם בַּחֹ֥דֶשׁ הָרִאשׁ֖וֹן
>   לֵאמֹֽר׃
>
> And the LORD spoke unto Moses in the wilderness of Sinai, in the first
>   month of the **second** year after they were come out of the land of
>   Egypt, saying

Numbers 9:3:

> בְּאַרְבָּעָ֣ה עָשָֽׂר־י֠וֹם בַּחֹ֨דֶשׁ הַזֶּ֜ה בֵּ֧ין הָֽעֲרְבַּ֛יִם
>   תַּעֲשׂ֥וּ אֹת֖וֹ בְּמוֹעֲד֑וֹ **כְּכָל־חֻקֹּתָ֥יו
>   וּכְכָל־מִשְׁפָּטָ֖יו תַּעֲשׂ֥וּ
>   אֹתֽוֹ׃**
>
> In the fourteenth day of this month, at dusk, ye shall keep it in its
>   appointed season; **according to all the statutes of it, and according
>   to all the ordinances thereof, shall ye keep it**.’

I assume that by stating that in the 2nd year they ate the Pesach lamb and performed all the commandments that should go with it, it includes the commandment of eating the lamb with matzah and maror, as well, as stated in:

> Exodus 12:8:
>
> וְאָכְל֥וּ אֶת־הַבָּשָׂ֖ר בַּלַּ֣יְלָה הַזֶּ֑ה **צְלִי־אֵ֣שׁ
>   וּמַצּ֔וֹת עַל־מְרֹרִ֖ים יֹאכְלֻֽהוּ׃**
>
> And they shall eat the flesh in that night, roast with fire, and
>   unleavened bread; with bitter herbs they shall eat it.

If they did everything completely, and they needed matzot, but, we see that they ran out of dough, how did they bake new matzot?

Or, is there a different way of understanding what occurred?

Comment: Why couldn't they make it from the mon itself? It's explicit that they turned it into ugos - a language used to refer to lafa type bread...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky interesting angle. Requires more research. One thing, perhaps, that would rule out using mahn. It says that it tasted like something fried in oil, which may nullify the idea that matzot must be "lechem oni" - also a term that Torah uses regarding Matzot.

Comment: Conversely, they refer to mahn as lechem k'lokel, degenerate bread. The laws of matzos have to do with the contents, not the taste. If you happen to have really sweet or fatty wheat, it would taste like it was kneaded with oil or honey while still being lechem oni.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky You keep me thinking ;-) "fatty" wheat is not something I'm familiar with, but, I can't argue with your point re taste being irrelevant, here. As for "degenrate" bread comment, we don't know if that's what it really was or their spur-of-the-moment perception of it as they were "fed up" with eating the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

They had money and there were various merchants travelling through the desert with whom they traded. Obviously these merchants who have particularly made an effort to travel towards them to sell as they knew they were willing buyers.

Although the people ate Manna as their daily staple, there were also meal offerings offered in the Mishkan and so they needed flour for those.

So, to put it simply, they bought it from travelling merchants.

Given that they had to ensure it wasn't chametz, at minimum they would have purchased unground wheat, and had access to mill-stones. The offerings in the Mishkan also used unleavened dough so it would probably have been a regular order but a much bigger one for Pesach.

Comment: Although this is a common answer for other item found in the hands of Bnei Yisroel in the desert, can we really say this for the flour/wheat needed for Shmura Matza? What about shmira from time of ketzira?

Comment: They probably bought unground wheat and then ground it themselves. However probably wasn't shmira from ketzira which is a chumra.

I suppose they could have sent some people along to watch the harvesting for such a large order.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but providing a source for this information would strengthen it. The Torah doesn't  mention trade or business dealings with anyone until near the end of their wandering, i.e. - buying food from Amon and Mo'av as mentioned in Devarim. In those cases, they went there. There is no mention of merchants coming to them in the desert. The spies brought some produce samples which MAYBE included wheat if you assume that wheat is called "pri ha'aretz" (it is one of the 7).

Comment: The spies didn't go to the land until after the 2nd Pesach. They left on their journey around 28th Sivan in the 2nd year and returned on 8th Av. (And Shelach L'cha is often read on 28th Sivan, and Devarim which also recalls the story on 8th Av).

Comment: @user6591 You are making an a priori assumption about *massoth shemuroth.* Most sources in the Rishonim and Geonim understand *shemurah* to be a reference to watching them carefully once the flour has been mixed with water and not from the time of *qessirah* at all. As far as the *man* being used for *massoth*, it could not be done because *massoth* can only be made from something that can become *hamess* - the *man* was not a species of wheat or barley and when it sat too long it *rotted* (*sirahon*), it did not undergo *himuss*. Kol tuv.

Comment: @DanF Why do you need explicit mention of merchants to believe it? The *benei yisrael* did not exit Egypt and enter into a vacuum. Try looking into the history behind the groups of merchants involved in the selling of Yosef HaSsaddiq. Merchants were there - *midbar* does not necessarily mean "arid desert" but more like "un[der]-developed, no man's land." People traveled it to and from major cities and outposts all the time. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist As a rule, when the Torah does NOT explicitly mention something, and neither Midrash nor any source whatseover mentions that something did or did not happen, a claim for or against any point would be speculative. Thus, to state that there was merchant trade in the desert, I think is speculative. This may be esp. true considering various verses in beginning of Devarim ans elsewhere that point to G-d's providing all the food in the desert esp. mahn and quail and water.

Comment: @DanF So when you go to work, get paid, and use that money to buy food, you don't need to thank HaShem because it didn't drop out of the sky or come out of a rock? Just because there is a *misgereth* doesn't mean that God didn't provide it. Yes, God provided *man*, quail, and water - but it does not say that He provided wheat. And if they kept Pesah then they got wheat from somehwere. Frankly, I would rather speculate that they got it from merchants rather than "speculate" that the spies brought back a "sample" big enough for all of Kelal Yisrael to eat *massoth*. Kol tuv.

Comment: @DanF The source for the merchant trade in the desert is Yoma 75b. Why not considering the answer of Ibn Ezra who is saying that the bnei Yisrael found Matsot at the station they were on Pesach the 2nd year. See Shemot 12:25